# Почему не работает AJAX запрос

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, redbeanphp

Есть html форма:

```
<div class="Contentlable mt-2">Регистрация</div>
    <div class="card" style="border-radius:15px;box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px green;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form class="form-signin" id="singup" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div for="name" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Comfortaa';color:black">Имя</div>
            <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Введите имя" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div for="surname" style="text-align:center;font-family:'Comfortaa';color:black">Фамилия</div>
            <input type="surname" name="surname" class="form-control" id="surneme" placeholder="Введите фамилию" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div for="login" class="col-3 col-form-label" style="font-family:'Comfortaa';color:black;">Логин</div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <input type="login" name="login" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Введите логин" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Password" class="col-3 col-form-label" style="font-family:'Comfortaa';color:black">Пароль</label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Email" class="col-3 col-form-label" style="font-family:'Comfortaa';color:black" >E-mail</label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"  id="email" placeholder="Введите e-mail" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="btn courseBlockBtn" type="submit" name="do_signup" id="submit" style="background:#212121;color:white;margin:0px;width:100%;height:35px;padding:0px;">Зарегистрироваться</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Есть, подключенный к этому html документу, js скрипт:

```
 $('#singup').submit(function(e){
    var login = $('#login').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../php/singup.php',
      data: {login:login, password:password, name:name, surname:surname, email:email}
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Файл signup.php к которому ведет ajax:

```
<?php 
    require "db.php";
    $data = $_POST;
    $errors = array();

    if (R::count('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login'])) > 0 ) {
      $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином уже существует!';
    }
    if (R::count('users', 'email = ?', array($data['email'])) > 0 ) {
      $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким email уже существует!';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $user = R::dispense('users');
        $user->name = $data['name'];
        $user->surname = $data['surname'];
        $user->login = $data['login'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $user->start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        R::store($user);
    }
    ?>
```

После нажатия кнопки #submit страница перезагружается и данные не заносятся в бд.

---

Когда делал тоже самое без ajax, данные заносились.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Почему в обработчике клика регистрируется обработчик сабмита?

Comment: Исправил, но это никак не повлияло на проблему

Comment: Теперь открывайте консоль разработчика и смотрите есть ли ошибки, проходит ли запрос и т.д.

Comment: И вы ведь в курсе что правильный тег `<?php`?

Comment: @u_mulder Да, опечатался) Ошибок в консоли нет, данные формы получены

Comment: Если вы уверены что данные получены - дебагайте свой php-скрипт. Проверяйте пустоту/непустоту `$errors`. А также тот факт что страница __перезагружается__ говорит что ошибка где-то __есть__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что js скрипт запускался до того, как DOM полностью загрузился. Решил я это добавив функцию `$(document).ready(function() {}`.
Полностью js скрипт теперь выглядит так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#singup').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: this.method, //POST
      url: this.action, //php/singup.php
      data: $(this).serialize(),
    })
    return false;
  })
});
```